# Exact number of character comparisons in naive exact algorithm

Tags: algorithm, string-matching

Given a substring and a string, is it possible to calculate the **exact** number of character comparisons made when running the naive exact algorithm to match the substring to the given string?  Assume exact match, no approximate match.

According to many sources (e.g., http://www.di.unipi.it/~pisanti/DIDATTICA/patternmatching1.pdf), it is possible to calculate the worse-case number of comparisons by using Big-Oh notation: `O(nm)`.  Namely, the worse-case is: `n(m-n+1)`, where `n` is the length of the substring that is to be matched to the string `m`.

However, the following source states that there are roughly `m` comparisons made in the naive exact algorithm: http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs312/2002sp/lectures/lec25.htm.  Note that they use `n` instead of `m` in their notation, but we both mean the same thing (I'm just staying consistent with the previous URL link).

In any case, this all got me to wondering whether it is possible to calculate exactly how many character comparisons are made when running the naive exact algorithm.  If we can know the worst-case and we can guess at roughly how many character comparisons are made approximately, surely there must be a way to calculate **exactly** how many character comparisons are made.

Comment: You can calculate ___exactly___ how many character comparison you make in a specific case (example: "abcd" "abde"), but what point does it serve? it will only be true for that exact case

Comment: Of course it is possible. Just increment a counter every time you make a comparison.

Comment: As for the exact upper bound, consider strings of `n` letters `a` and `m` letters `a`. For a fixed `m`, when `n = m/2` (maybe plus or minus one), the number of comparisons will be the maximum possible.

Comment: @Gassa So if, for example, you've made 1000 alignments and you want to know how many character comparisons you've made... then can you explain a little more what you mean by increment a counter?

Comment: @warship `if (s[i] == t[j])` transforms into `if (eq (s[i], t[j]))` where `eq (x, y) is {counter += 1; return x == y;}`.

Comment: @Gassa I'm in Python.  I saw your CV, I think we speak the same language :-)  Can I send you a personal email to your gmail inbox provided on your CV?  This comments section is too small to show what I'm talking about...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the search is performed with an outer loop on the string length and an inner loop on the substring length, you will perform

- if the search succeeds at the `I`-th position, exactly `N.I` comparisons (`1≤I≤M-N+1`);
- if the search fails, exactly `ΣJk` comparisons, where the `Jk`'s are the numbers of matching characters in the substring prefixes, plus one (`1≤Jk≤N`).

As said, the worst case is `N(M-N+1)`, when all possible comparisons are made. The best case is the minimum of `N`, when the substring is found in the first position, and `M-N+1`, when all substring comparisons immediately fail.

Assuming that the probability of a failure is `q` and that of a success `p`, with all positions and all matching prefix lengths being equiprobable (if this is possible), the expected number is

```
p.N(M-N+2)/2 + q.(N+1)(M-N+1)/2 = N(M-N+2)/2 + q(M-1)/2.
```

Comment: Updated, the `Jk` are one unit higher, to detect the first mismatch.